# C# If Contains?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line-interface, contains

I am new to `C#` and I'm trying to write a contains statement. I want the process to read the `test` variable and if it contains the word error then print the variable if it does not contain an error then print no error. I think my process is close except when I run the code below I get an error when the CLI runs.

> "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Any help would be appreciated!

```
        while (true)
        {
            test = queue.GetMessage();
            if (test.AsString.Contains("error"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Variable: {0}", test.AsString));

            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("No Error: {0}", test.AsString));
        }
```

Comment: you could tell us at least on which line the error occurs...

Comment: Maybe you should check if (test == null).

Comment: Something is `null` in your code. Either `test`, or whatever is returned from `AsString`. Why aren't you overriding `ToString` anyway?

Comment: Or if AsString is null. You can provide a ToString() override to the test object.

Comment: Agree with nim. Either test is null, or queue was never fully define / created.

Comment: What do you want the message to be when `queue.GetMessage()` is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `queue.GetMessage()` return a string, then you don't need `AsString`. If you want to convert it to a string, `override ToString()`.

```
while (true) {
    test = queue.GetMessage();
    if (test.ToString().Contains("error")) {
        ...
    } else { 
        ...
    }
}
```

You can always guarantee that `ToString()` will be present because it's defined in the `object` base class. Just be sure it returns something intelligible, because default implementations may not.

Answer (score 2):

```
var message = queue.GetMessage()?? string.Empty;
var formattedMessage =
            String.Format(
                (message.IndexOf("error", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                    ? "No Error: {0}"
                    : "Variable: {0}", message);
Console.WriteLine(formattedMessage);
```

Useful references:

1. [Unique ways to use the Null Coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278703/unique-ways-to-use-the-null-coalescing-operator)
2. [Simplify conditional string format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154493/442444)

Comment: String.Equals != Contains ?

Comment: @abhitalks Sorry for the hasty edit.. Now I have corrected the mistake